# When to refresh token in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, jwt, authorization

Where should i call a refresh token request in websocket app (i'm using socket.io)?

Is there a way to re-emit particular socket.io event if server sent 'not authorized' error in response to the first attempt? Something like `axios.interceptors` for websockets?

Thank you!